# How do I install Zend OPcache Extension on my Media Temple Grid Server site?

Tags: shared-hosting, opcache, mediatemple

CMS's like Drupal 8 strongly recommend that you enable OPcache on your server to speed up page rendering. How does one install this extension if your site is hosted on Media Temple's shared Grid server service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Log in to your Media Temple account and go to the Admin section for your domain.
2. Under *File Management* click the *File Manager* link
3. Navigate to the `/etc` folder. If there is a file there called `php.ini` skip to step 5
4. Rename the file `php.ini.sample` to `php.ini`
5. Open the file `php.ini` and add the following lines to the bottom of that file:

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/php-7.2.12/lib/php/20170718/opcache.so
opcache.enable=1
```

I believe this assumes you are running php 7.2.12, so the URL may change if and when PHP is updated on the grid.